# How to convert a list of Slick queries into union

Tags: slick-3.0, scala-2.11

I have a query method that returns Slick queries. I want to do an union on all the queries that are returned. What would be the ideal way in scala to convert the list of queries into a union or ++ statement?

```
def accum() { firstList.flatMap{a => 
                  secondList.Map{b=> query(a,b)
                 }
               }
      }

def query(a:String, b:String): Query[T] { 
            //return Slick query
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do

```
var firstQuery = queries.head
val queriesNoHead = queries.drop(0)

for( q <- queriesNoHead ){
  firstQuery = firstQuery union q
}
```

And then `firstQuery` would be the union query